# Using lazy or eager fetch for creation of models in Java jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, fetch

I would like to know, how can I use better fetch parameter for entities, which have relation ManyToMany (or OneToMany).

For example, I have two entities: Task and Answer. One task has list of answers.
Sometimes, I would like to get only Task entity without answer, but also I need to get Task with list Answers.

If I use parameters fetch as Lazy on @OneToMany or @ManyToMany - without answers I can easy get task by id for example, but for getting Task with Answers I can use join fetch in hql query - problem that each answer has object Task as field and getting recursive query. (Task -> List -> each Answer -> Task -> List ...).

How can I avoid it?

I have some idea use sql query and get answers by TaskId, but get some fields of answer without Task with the help of ResultSet and create this entity Answer.

Can you have any ideas? Thanks.

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Answer.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "task")
    private Set<Answer> answers;

    ...
}


@Entity 
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    private Task task;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Show us your mapping entities

Comment: Ok. Above I show this entities.

Comment: Ok one more thing, do you have equals and hascode overriden in those entities.. if so, please attach the code.

Comment: I use generated hashcode and equals in idea. Why hashcode and hashcode influence on lazy init?

Comment: It may if you put the dependent entities inside. If you would include them would be beneficial..